# Tax Calculation of each employee in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I want to calculate monthly TDS rate for each and every employee(According to Indian Statutory). After calculating this TDS rate,This would be deducted from respective NET salary of employee every month.

For this I've tried Salary rule(Specially Python Code)in odoo 8 but it won't work properly as I needed. So Is it another way to calculate TDS for each employee?

Thanks in advance.